# .JS File caching issue in ASP.NET web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, browser-cache

We have a ASP.NET web application. In this we to handle the .css caching issue we use the below code in PreRender in BasePage,

```
if (Page.Header != null)
{
    foreach (Control currentLlink in Page.Header.Controls)
    {    
        if (currentLlink is HtmlLink)
        {
            HtmlLink cssLink = currentLlink as HtmlLink;
            if (cssLink.Attributes["type"].ToLower().Equals("text/css", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (cssLink.Attributes["href"].Contains(".css"))
                {
                    cssLink.Attributes["href"] += "?v=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSSFileVersion"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Now we have a new requirement to handle th .js files same as the above. I have handled it like below,

```
if (Page.Header != null)
{
    foreach (Control currentLlink in Page.Header.Controls)
    {
        if (currentLlink is LiteralControl)
        {
            LiteralControl jsLink = currentLlink as LiteralControl;

            if (((System.Web.UI.LiteralControl)currentLlink).Text.ToLower().Contains(".js"))
            {
                ((System.Web.UI.LiteralControl)currentLlink).Text = ((System.Web.UI.LiteralControl)currentLlink).Text.ToLower().Replace(".js", ".js?v=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JSFileVersion"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code we achieve the mentioned requirement. but however some .js files are not replaced using this. Some .js links are not even listing up as 'LiteralControl'. Is there a way to display all the .js files added in a particular .aspx page via code behind. i want to handle it somewhere commonly like the above code i used in pre handle.

Is there anyone else came across a scenario like this.
All suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by some .js files are not replaced? Are they outside the header, perhaps? Can you post some examples of the js files that are not picked-up?

Comment: Hi Ted, some js files are added inside the header of the respectively aspx page. but still they are not picking up. JS files are similar to other js files (contains custom methods written  by me).

Comment: can you show us an example of a link that isn't replaced?

Comment: Hi Ted, Some links are not even listing up as 'LiteralControl'. JS files that are available in that foreach are getting replaced correctly. What my problem is, some js files are not even listing up.

Comment: I understand that, I'm still waiting for an example...

Comment: Hi Ted, On further analysis it seems like the .js files embed  in the .aspx page are getting processed correctly. however the .js files added in the UserControl are not getting processed.

Comment: Add the same code on the user control's page_load event

Comment: Yeah, i know that. but i want to handle it in one place commonly in BasePage. or some solutions like that. I have hundreds of UserControls so assume.